# Recovery an EtherWallet with seed ( WIF form )

Tags: myetherwallet

Recovery an EtherWallet with seed. I had  an Etherwallet 5 years ago. My private key 35 caracters/alpha numerics : "3P7.........cW"  it ooks like WIF form. I have password, ID but i cannot remenber from where I created my wallet.
I try with MEW but it doesn't go.
Please do you have ideas to find my wallet again.
Thanks

Comment: In base 58 and start with a 3 it looks like a bitcoin segwit address.

Comment: Oui je le pense aussi que c'est une adresse donc rien à voir avec ce que je croyais. Enfin si je peux avoir d'autres avis ce serait bien.